# Service and launching/re-launching Activity

Tags: android, service, android-activity

I am developing an app which runs has a basic UI and  service which can receive emergencies'. If the user is in the UI and presses home or Back a notification appears and the service continues to run. If an emergency is received by the service I want to open the Activity into the UI. To do this I have to use startActivity in the service with the Intent flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK.

But this means that, if the UI is still running in the background, it doesn't get re-opened. Many of my UI interactions from that point onward seem to happen on the old, hidden UI not the new UI which is open. Also If i close the current UI I sometimes have the old UI behind it.

I would like that from a service I can either bring the old ui to the front OR open a new one, depending whether or not the old UI is still running.

I have tried using FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK and FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK together to both clear any other instances of the UI then open the UI in a new task but CLEAR_TASK is API 11 and over; my app supports 10.

Any help on the above is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I've done with this is do a `bindService` in the Activity's `onResume` (so you get the `Service` instance) and then add a method to the `Service` instance that receives a `Handler` instance from the `Activity`. In `onPause` you set the `Handler` on the `Service` to null. This way the `Service` knows (by checking its internal `Handler` instance) if there is already a UI available. If there is, it sends the `Handler` a `Message` that things happened. If there is no `Handler`, it launches a new UI.

Comment: Looks like I'm going to go with this option. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to choose the launch mode "singleTask" in your manifest file :

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTask" >
```

With the "singleTask" launch mode, your activity will be instanciated only one time.

Comment: Unfortunately this conflicts with the CLEAR_TOP flag that must be used in a Service to launch an Activity