# A service to launch an Activity

Tags: java, android, service

I have started a service when my main app is backgrounded and then use the service short cut icon to relaunch my app. but every time a new instance is created for the app. I want to preserve the ui.

I have tried setting flags while starting the intent in service

This is the code from my service

```
appLogoImage.setOnClickListener(v -> {
  Intent intent = new Intent(MinimizedAppFABService.this,MainActivity.class);
  //WS intent.addFlags(Intent.);
  startActivity(intent);
  //close the service and remove the chat heads
  stopSelf();
});
```

expected to launch a existing view if the app is still not cleared from memory, and is if its cleared then relaunch as a new Activity

Comment: http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I go a solution from stackover flow,

```
<activity
android:name=".MainActivity"
android:launchMode="singleTask" >
```

I added `android:launchMode="singleTask"`
the link to the answer is [Service and launching/re-launching Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17239462/service-and-launching-re-launching-activity)